# How to rename a file using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to append a string to my file name and change the extension file.
I tried this, I can only change the extension file, but can not append the string to the name

```
$String = "123"
$File = Get-ChildItem "E:\Folder\*.txt" | Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName "E:\Folder\$String\$($_.BaseName).csv"
```

`.txt` file  name is : `Report.txt`
My expectation file : `123_Report.csv`

#### Updated

```
$File = Get-ChildItem "$Sel_JobFolder\*.txt" | Rename-Item -NewName { "$String`_" + $_.Name.Replace('.txt','.csv')}
```

Comment: Can you try NewName = "E:\Folder\$($String)_$($_.BaseName).csv"

Comment: No, Its not working

Comment: Strange, it worked for me, with a fixed value for BaseName. What result did you get?

Comment: Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null. Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewNam ...

Comment: Does `Get-ChildItem "E:\Folder\*.txt"` give you anything?

Comment: I got It. I updated. THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$File = Get-ChildItem "E:\Folder\*.txt" | foreach  { Rename-Item -path $_ -NewName "$($String)_$($_.BaseName).csv" }
```